# Else python syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to run a piece of code with python. However, I get a syntax error in "else:". I have no idea where the error is. Any suggestions would help. Thanks for any suggestions.

**Screenshot of code:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64cW6GC-lWCY01LSnVMSHNrNkE/view?usp=sharing

**Screenshot of error:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64cW6GC-lWCWlBxUjlpVnFaaU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The `else` should be indented the same amount as the corresponding `if`.

Comment: Tip: Copy and paste code and error messages in your post directly. Don't make screenshots if it's just about text.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 2):

You made a little mistake with indentation.

```
if temperature >= (0 * 9/5 + 32):
    print("Not Freezing")
else:
    print("Freezing")
```

If/else is one logic block and has to be on same level of indentation.